# transition of image to another image on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I want transition of image to another image when hover. But after using the following code the size of the image is more than the page and when hover the image disappears and no other image can be seen.

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
     <title></title>
     </head>
    <body>
      <div id="cssfade">
       <img src="image1.jpg" height:200px;width:300px;/>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#cssfade { 
    background-image: url('image2.jpg');
    height:200px; 
    width: 300px;
}
#cssfade img {
    -webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 1s;
    -o-transition: all ease 1s;
    -ms-transition: all ease 1s;
    transition: all ease 1s;
}
#cssfade img:hover {
    opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest putting one image over the other (if as a background image, one div on top of other) and on hover change opacity, than there won't be gliching/white flashing between.

Comment: Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/es_kaija/ox6v7g6m/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming the image in the div is content so I have left it there and merely moved the hover to take effect when the wrapping div is hovered.

```css
#cssfade {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/sports/2/);
}
#cssfade img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}
#cssfade:hover img {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="cssfade">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/sports/1/" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `background-image` on `div`.

On `hover` change the `background-image`.

Transition:

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition)
[**CSS Tricks**](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/)

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/9u6uu9m5/1/)

```css
#cssfade {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200');
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}
#cssfade:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 1s;
  -o-transition: all ease 1s;
  -ms-transition: all ease 1s;
  transition: all ease 1s;
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1');
}
```

```html
<div id="cssfade"></div>
```

Comment: it would be better if you explain a bit your css properties i.e. `-webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 1s;
  -o-transition: all ease 1s;
  -ms-transition: all ease 1s;
  transition: all ease 1s;`

Comment: ^All the different variations are for cross-browser compatibility, pretty sure

Answer (score 2):

EDIT - Just to clarify the difference to [Tushar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2025923/tushar)'s answer, the transitions should be on `#cssfade` rather than `#cssfade:hover` to ensure the transition applies when hovering **and** un-hovering.

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>...</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="cssfade"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#cssfade { 
  height:200px; 
  width: 300px;
  background-image: url('image1.jpg') no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 1s;
  -o-transition: all ease 1s;
  -ms-transition: all ease 1s;
  transition: all ease 1s;
}

#cssfade:hover {
  background-image: url('image2.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: it would be better if you explain a bit your css properties i.e. `-webkit-transition: all ease 1s; -moz-transition: all ease 1s; -o-transition: all ease 1s; -ms-transition: all ease 1s; transition: all ease 1s;`

Comment: Why do I need to explain CSS properties the asker was already attempting to use? I'm happy to clarify if the asker requests this but given these properties were in their question I'm presuming they already know their purpose.